# Nondifferentiable coordinate transforms

Tags: pde, ode, integration, coordinate-transform

Suppose that we have coordinates $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that $v$ is not differentiable when $u(x,y)=u_0$ where $u_0$ is a constant. Can we solve a differential equation, such as the Schrödinger equation, using these coordinates? Can we compute integrals involving the Jacobian determinant in these coordinates?

Comment: The transformation is not-differentiable at some points only, or non-differentiable everywhere, at every point?

Comment: Nondifferentiable only at points $u(x,y,z)=u_0$ where $u_0$ is a constant.

Comment: What's the domain on which you pose the differential equation? Is it a subset of $(x,y,z)$ space, or a subset of $(u,v,z)$ space?

Comment: For solution of a differential equation there should not be any major problem. In the worst case, a matching condition would have to be formulated for the locations where the coordinate transformation is not differentiable. For the Jacobian, would be ok too, if the singularity is integrable.

Comment: The original differential equation is given in $(x,y)$ space and then the variables are changed to obtain a differential equation in $(u,v)$ space.

Comment: @TommiHöynälänmaa, please add those details to the question.

Comment: I think I struggle with what to do with the question. I have ideas, but it's entirely clear to me why anyone would want to transform a problem posed in $(x,y)$ space, transform it into $(u,v)$ space, and solve it there with a non-differentiable transform. What's the purpose and background of the question that I'm not getting?

Comment: The coordinate system arose when I started with using distances from two fixed points as coordinates.

Comment: Right, but why would you do that? It seems like an unsuitable parameterization for the purposes of solving a PDE.

Comment: I need to solve the Schrödinger equation for a two atom system so that small balls centered at the nuclei are excluded from the domain. The reason for this is to handle the singularities of the potential at the nuclei. I'm actually using another solution for this problem now.

Comment: Ah, but if you exclude the nuclei, then you also exclude the locations where your coordinate transformation is non-smooth. Right?